# Prolog: existence error

Tags: prolog

I'm running into an existence error with my prolog code below. Certainly not an expert at prolog, but why is the procedure not being recognized?

Any ideas or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

**Compilation process:**

1. gprolog test.pl
2. [test].
3. :- foo(P,S,B,O,M).

> uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,(+)/2),foo/5)

**Code:**

```
foo(P, S, B, O, M):-     
    % Pepperoni at weight 4 each

    member(P,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]),


    % Sausage at weight 10 each

    member(S,[0,1,2,3,4]),


    % Bacon at weight 6 each

    member(B,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),


    % Onion at weight 5 each

    member(O,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),


    % Mushroom at weight 7 each

    member(M,[0,1,2,3,4]),


    % next figure out the pizza weight
    4*P + 10*S + 6*B + 5*O, 7*M,
    S =< 40, 

    % calculate remaining pepperoni if weight is low
    P is 40 - S.
```

Comment: Those two are just arithmetic expressions: `4*P + 10*S + 6*B + 5*O, 7*M,` you would have to evaluate them with `is/2` maybe?

Comment: @Boris What about the exception error, though? Currently, I'm not able to run the code, says "foo" procedure doesn't exist? Or maybe I'm not understanding the error message.

Comment: Did you try to find what gives you the error? Maybe it is the code I pasted from your question into my comment above?

Comment: Right below `% next figure out the pizza weight`, those are two arithmetic expressions hanging in the air, you need to evaluate them, compare them to each other, something. This is what the `+/2` procedure error is about

Comment: @Boris Got it! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!